# How to send message from one device to other device outside of an Activity?

Tags: android, messaging

How can I implement code for sending messages to another device?

A method like

```
public void sndSms(String phoneNumber, String message)
```

Note: My class doesn't have `extends Activity` and `onCreate()` method. How can I implement `sndSms()` method then?

Comment: plz help me any one of you i am waiting for your response

Comment: Chill out! Do you have anything so far? Do you know that you can pass the `Context` to a non-activity class in order to start an `Intent`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found this solution, when I thought I will have that problem as well. But it was not necessary for me.

http://www.dotnetexpertsforum.com/how-to-send-sms-programatically-in-android-t1548.html

Answer (score 1):

I guess you've got to have an activity at some point. So you just need to pass its Context to your method.

```
public void sndSms(String phoneNumber, String message, Context context){
     Intent smsIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
     (...)
     context.startActivity(smsIntent);
}
```

In activity simply use

```
xxx.sndSms("number", "message", myActivity.this);
```